# What is the etymology of the kanji 石?

Tags: kanji, etymology

Kanji "stone"  contains (cliff 厂 + mouth 口).. my question is what is the idea of mixing mouth with cliff ... the cliff function here is clear because it's some thing related with stone.. but what is the mouth function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

「石」was originally

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3212
[合集13505](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=13505&jgwfl=)</kbd>

which  is a depiction of *stone chimes*. The original meaning of「石」is *stone, rock*.

> There was an ancient musical instrument made out of stone chimes called「磬」.「磬」was originally「声」, which depicts *stone chimes*「石」suspended with *threads/string* (now looking like「士」as the top part of「声」). In the character「声」, the *stone chimes* component「石」is written as「」.
>
> Later, *a hand holding a striking implement*「殳」was added onto「声」, forming「殸」, to emphasise that the instrument is meant to be struck. Finally, another semantic「石」(*rock, stone*) was added on to「殸」, as a further emphasis that the instrument was made of stone.
>
> <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [前](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)7.42.1
> [合集8613](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=8613&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
> 金
> [image]
> 鎛</kbd>
> 　
> <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [石部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=57)
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>今
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>
>
> In modern Japanese,「声」is used to represent another word, which was originally written as「聲」(*sound*, extended to mean *voice*).「聲」([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese?wprov=srpw1_0#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_%282014%29): **/*[l̥]eŋ/**) is a compound of「殸」(**/*[C.qʰ]ˤeŋ-s/**, *stone chimes being struck*) and「耳」(*ear*), indicating the meaning *sound*.

A *distinguishing symbol*「口」was added to mark the name of an ancient region called「石」. This distinguishing symbol has been inherited in some variants of the character up until the modern form of「石」.

<kbd>商
甲
[image]
[乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1277
[合集376](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=376&jgwfl=)</kbd>

> *Distinguishing symbols* were often added to existing characters to form new characters, and some of these symbols are inherited in the modern form. The symbol「口」or its derivatives「甘・曰」was added to a few older characters to form proper nouns (names of states/regions), such as「商」([*Shang Dynasty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)),「周」([*Zhou Dynasty*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty)),「曹」([*State of Cao*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cao_(state))),「曾」([*State of Zeng*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sui_(state))), etc, and their modern forms have permanently inherited this symbol (regardless of whether they're used to represent a proper noun or not).

The *stone chimes* component was later simplified into「厂」, then the strokes were further altered slightly into「丆」, resulting in the modern shape.

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
金
[image]
己侯貉子簋
[集成3977](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=3977&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image]
景北海碑陰</kbd>
　<kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

---

There are characters built from variants of「石」which may or may not have the distinguishing symbol「口」. In fact,「石」was subject to several different shape changes across different characters, obscuring their connection to「石」:

- In some characters, a few strokes in the form of horizontal lines (probably *decorative* with no meaningful function) were added on to「石」, as seen in the second form of「声・殸・磬」.

  <kbd>[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
  [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
  [image]
  80
  荊門包山2</kbd><kbd>楚
  簡
  [image: <]
  199
  荊門包山2</kbd>

  These shapes are present (without「口」) in e.g.:

  - 「叚」

    <kbd>西周
    金
    [image]
    盠尊
    [集成6013](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=6013&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>春秋
    金
    [image]
    曾伯陭壺
    [集成9712](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9712&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
    簡
    [image]
    秦律十八77
    [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
    楷
    [image]</kbd>
  - 「段」

    <kbd>西周
    金
    [image]
    段簋
    [集成4208](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4208&jgwfl=)</kbd>
    <kbd>篆
    [image]
    [殳部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=109)
    說文解字</kbd><kbd>今
    楷
    [image]</kbd>
- In some characters,「石」is written as「⿸广廿」, such as in「度」,「席」, and「庶」.

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [珠](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)979
  [合集10399](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=10399&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  伯庶父簋
  [集成3983](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=3983&jgwfl=)</kbd>
  <kbd>篆
  [image]
  [广部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=54)
  說文解字</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>

Comment: Great answer. Out of interest @droooze, what's the source that you're using for the characters?

Comment: @jogloran do you mean the pictures? I mainly get them from http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/, which normally covers everything up to Qin bamboo and slip writing and Shuowen small seal script forms. If I need clerical script shapes I usually go to http://chinese-linguipedia.org/search_source.html.